# wget to download dynamic website which uses aspx

Tags: asp.net, download, wget

I m trying to download entire website using wget for offline learning.

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites 
--html-extension --convert-links  
--restrict-file-names=windows  --domains scmhrd.edu   
--no-parent  http://elearning.scmhrd.edu/frmSet.aspx
```

All the static content gets downloaded but not the dynamic contents . Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: No there isn't. You don't have access to the server-side code from HTTP.

Comment: but the website you are trying to download is under construction :D

Comment: ha ha yeah , it wasnt that time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to download server side code from HTTP. That's why asp.net rules!